# CSS Border Tapering

Tags: css

CSS borders taper by default (as in the left side of this example):

[image: Tapering Borders]

Is there a way to get borders to behave like the right side of the example?

Comment: You could wrap your `<div>` in another `<div>`, give the inner `<div>` the top and bottom borders and the outer `<div>` the left and right borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to modify the default jointing options, but there are a couple of workarounds.

**Option 1:**
If you can add another `<div>` element around the first one, you cans imply apply a left and right border to the outer `<div>`, and a top and bottom border to the inner one:

```css
body > div {
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
  border-right: 10px solid green;
}

div > div {
  border-bottom: 10px solid gold;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    A div element with a border
  </div>
</div>
```

**2: Using `before` and `after` psuedo-elements:**
If you can't modify the DOM, you could use the `before` and `after` pseudo-elements as follows:

```css
div {
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
  border-right: 10px solid green;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

div::before { background: red; top: 0 }
div::after  { background: gold; 0: 0 }
```

```html
<div>
  A div element with a border
</div>
```

**Note:** In order to use this method, we must also set padding on the `<div>` element itself in order to allow us to position the 'borders'.

Comment: Thanks to you and Scath below. Exactly what I needed (and should have thought of myself).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any solution that would change the rendering of the border, but you could nest two `divs` and overlap them.

```css
.inner {
   border-top: 20px solid red;
   border-bottom: 20px solid orange;
   height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.outer {
   border-left: 20px solid blue;
   border-right: 20px solid green;
   height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Two div elements with borders.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one element and gradient:

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  background: 
   conic-gradient(at top    20px left  20px,
      red 90deg, #0000 0 180deg, blue 0) 0,
   conic-gradient(at bottom 20px right 20px,
      green 180deg, orange 0 270deg, #0000 0) 100%;
  background-size: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Two div elements with borders.
</div>
```

Comment: @canon not necessarely because we can decrease the size of gradient and avoid the overlap, I made it simple by always adding `100%` but it can be replaced by `calc(100% - 40px)`and then the order will not matter, all depend on the visual you want to obtain

Answer (score 0):

You can use `div::after` to do what you want with a single `div` like this:

```css
div {
  border-right: 10px solid green;
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 10px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="d2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Box-shadows could do that

```css
div {
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 10px solid orange;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 green, -10px 0 0 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```